# How to fit Vector3 in array for random choose

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im trying to do something like this

```
    var cord_1 = new Vector3(91.71f, 22, 62.34f);
    var cord_2 = new Vector3(93.65f, 22, 61.47f); 
    var cord_3 = new Vector3(91.65f, 22, 66.47f);
```

But in some array or list and randomly choose one of these

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Vector3> coordinates = new List<Vector3> 
{
  new Vector3(91.71f, 22, 62.34f),
  new Vector3(93.65f, 22, 61.47f), 
  new Vector3(91.65f, 22, 66.47f)
}

Vector3 randomlyChosenCoordinate = coordinates[Random.Range(0, coordinates.Count -1)];
```